# Turning off SSL is IIS version 10

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016, iis-10

We have a server running Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10 installed , hosting a database with a front end website attached to it which displays the data on a TV mounted in the workshop.

Problem we are having it is every time the server is restarted, or an update is installed SSl turns on. Sometimes it can go for weeks without an issue but all of a sudden it turns on. Is there a way that we can force SSL to be turned off in IIS without breaking the Exchange OWA?

Comment: What does this have to do with OWA? Are you hosting this database and website on your Exchange server?

Comment: Exchange/OWA might modify Windows HTTP API settings in order to keep itself healthy, but that can have an impact on your IIS sites, if they happen to have certain site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html You cannot find a solution without learning more about the problem first.

Comment: Usually, I used IISCrypto to manage the protocols(e.g. SSL, TLS) on clients/servers.
**>> without breaking the Exchange OWA** Maybe you could try unchecking the Required SSL checkbox for OWA virtual directory.

Comment: Hi, any update?